# Trying to use filter with jsonApi (Maven project + Elide) and gets this error : InvalidPredicateException: Invalid filter format

Tags: maven, json-api, elide

Everything works fine until I start including filter in my `Get` request.
Following is the request that I am trying:

```
/message/1/clickMessages?filter[clickMessages][recipientEmail]='e@gamil.com'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the filter should be

`/message/1/clickMessages?filter[clickMessages]=recipientEmail=='e@gamil.com'`

The query parameters would need to be url encoded

`/message/1/clickMessages?filter%5BclickMessages%5D%=recipientEmail%3D%3D%27e%40gamil.com%27`

Comment: it works thank you also  :    /clickMessages?filter=recipientEmail=='e@gamil.com' works too

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
/message/1/clickMessages?filter[clickMessages.recipientEmail]='e@gmail.com'
```